# Not working Count to Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I need show grid when Count > 0, else collapse it.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Visibility="{Binding Num.Count, Converter={StaticResource IntToVisibleConverter}}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="Image.jpg"
                        Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TextBlock, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Text="{Binding Num, Converter={StaticResource NumStrConverter}}"/>
                </Grid>
```

I use this converter

```
class IntToVisibleConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        int val = (int) value;
        if (val == 0)
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
...
}

public IEnumerable<string> Num{ get; set;}
```

image show image.jpg when Count==0

Comment: Does the count have a property changed trigger in this case? What is the num object, a List or ObservableCollection?

Comment: I've writed public IEnumerable<string> Num{ get; set;}

Comment: Switch it to an ObservableCollection<T> instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I only saw it after posting, and how is all this data bound to your grid? IEnumarable<string> will not update any of its bindings when changed, as it doesn't implement CollectionChanged nor PropertyChanged

Comment: `Num.Count` is an extension method, not a property.

Comment: @Chris is correct, `Count` does not exist for an `IEnumerable` which would most likely result in a Binding error for you. For a working solution of checking if a collection is empty or not, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1509238/238902)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Num` is `IEnumerable<string>`, when you write `Num.Count` you are actually referring to the `Count` extension method. Binding in WPF works with properties, so that won't work. If you look at the debug output, you should get a binding error.

So, you need to make sure you bind to a property, not a method. Like Default mentions, switch to `ObservableCollection<T>` or something similar, that will both give you a `Count` *property*, and update notifications whenever the collection changes.